# Python + Blessed: how to avoid the flickering when clearing the screen very frequently

Tags: python, terminal, flicker

**What I am doing**

Versions: *Linux + Python 2.7 + Blessed 1.14.1*

I have text strings continuously updating on terminal. Refresh rate is about 0.1 seconds.

They have different size and I clear the screen before printing back all the current values.

**Problem**

The terminal flickers when `Terminal.clear()` is called so often.

**Possible (ugly) solution**

I could pad each line to have fixed length and overlap it on the old text, but this is not *elegant*. I would imagine there is a better way to accomplish this.

*EDIT*

Pending a term.clear_eol (clear till end of line) is far more efficient than pad each line with blanks:

```
print(term.bold_white_on_red("text") + term.clear_eol)
```

Off course `print(term.clear())` at the beginning must be removed to avoid the flickering.

**Question**

In *curses* I could use `curses.erase()` instead of `curses.clear()`, but I couldn't find any `erase()` in *Blessed*. Is there any other (obvious) solution that I am overlooking?

(PS: I already read all available docs. While I know quite a bit of *curses* I would like to start using *Blessed* because it is far easier.)

Comment: You'd have to write your own - blessed/blessings is just terminfo with a nicer *calling* interface, but no optimization.  curses does optimization.  With optimization, your application recalls what's on the screen and how to update it without a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasDickey. 
It is strange that nobody is annoyed by the flickering as it is, at least in my case, very visible.